# Loops for 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix A with dimensional (45x500x5).

I would like to use MATLAB loops to extract data from the matrix as follow in which the first component are from 1 to 45; the third are from 1 to 5.

```
data 1 = [A(1,:,1)];
data 2 = [A(2,:,1) A(1,:,2)];
data 3 = [A(3,:,1) A(2,:,2) A(1,:,3)];
data 4 = [A(4,:,1) A(3,:,2) A(2,:,3) A(1,:,4)];
data 5 = [A(5,:,1) A(4,:,2) A(3,:,3) A(2,:,4) A(1,:,5)];
data 6 = [A(6,:,1) A(5,:,2) A(4,:,3) A(3,:,4) A(2,:,5)];
data 7 = [A(7,:,1) A(6,:,2) A(5,:,3) A(4,:,4) A(3,:,5)];
```

and so on, up to:

```
data 45 = [A(45,:,1) A(44,:,2)] A(43,:,3) A(42,:,4) A(41,:,5)];
```

I am very new in MATLAB. Could anyone help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are more efficient ways to do this without `for` loops, but if you must insist on it, then you can create a `for` loop from 1 to 45.  For each iteration, you would use the current loop index, then create  decreasing linear indices in the fashion that you have specified.  You'll also need to use an `if` statement to ensure we don't go out of bounds when specifying the first dimension's decreasing indices.  As such:

```
for idx = 1 : 45
    if idx < 5
        data = A(idx:-1:1,:,1:idx);
    else
        data = A(idx:-1:idx-4,:,1:5);
    end
    %// Do your processing with data here
    %// ...
end
```

`data` will contain the desired matrix at each iteration.